# starting a gui application on boot up after starting of window manager on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am using fluxbox window manager on raspian os and I want a gui application every raspberry reboots. I have included the gui starting line in .xinitrc but it is not working. Contents of .xinitrc file

```
!#/bin/sh
sudo /home/pi/df.py
```

where df.py in python gui application. How can I solve this problem? I want to start gui application after fuxbox window manager in started.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
        sudo python /home/pi/df.py
```

Comment: df.py is executable file so should it not start with just sudo df.py. I did chmod +x df.py. I also include !#/usr/bin/python at the top of file. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Try sudo ./home/pi/df.py

Comment: ok I tried sudo python /home/pi/df.py but it is still not working.

Comment: @user2673943 did you try with the period before the path?

Comment: sorry I have not understood but what is period before the path?

Comment: Period(.) in the shell before the filepatg usually makes things execute.

Comment: yes I tried that also but it is not working. Well in any case sudo python df.py should also work but it is not working

Comment: @user2673943 Try 'exec /home/pi/df.py'